# Register parameter for "inout cursor" type using Spring JDBCTemplet/StoredProcedure

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, java-stored-procedures

I have a requirement to call an oracle procedure using SpringJDBC Template. I was able to call several procedure that had IN or OUT parameters. But, recently, I got requirement to write a "Spring DAO procedure" that has one attribute of "INOUT" and "cursor" type. Specifically, I don't know hot to register "inout" "cursor" type parameters using JDBCTemplate/StoredProcedure.

**Oracle Procedure details:**

Name:- testin_proc(varchar in param1,cursor_type inout param2,varchar in param3)
    Where 
            param1 is IN parameter
            param2 is INOUT parameter
            param3 is IN parameter.

```
The param2 is cursor type and the cursor has the query string 
that contains multiple attributes. For example,
 (select attribut1, attribut2, attribut3, 
    attribut4 from table where xyz=param1 and abc=param2).
```

The below link describes to consider INOUT parameters map as array of the parameter type. Though this piece of code accomplishes the task without using spring jdbc template etc. It includes 5 Steps. Ref:- http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefjdbc75719.html

```
Step 1:-
    //Call it this way
    CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall(
        "{CALL doubleMyInt(?)}");
Step 2:-
    //register it this way
    call.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
Step 3:-
    //Set the input this way
    call.setInt(1,10);
Step 4:-
    // execute
    call.execute();
Step 5:-
    //Retrieve it this way
    int retval = call.getInt(1);
```

So far so good. However, I am stuck at converting this to Spring JDBCTemplet/StoredProcedure. Mainly, registration part of inout cursor type parameter using Spring JDBCTemplet/StoredProcedure

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Things that I googled:-

**Sample1:-**

```
SqlParameter firstName = new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR);
SqlOutParameter outParameter = new SqlOutParameter("firstName", Types.VARCHAR);
List<SqlParameter> paramList = new ArrayList<SqlParameter>();
paramList.add(firstName);
paramList.add(outParameter);    
final String procedureCall = "{call testin_proc(?, ?, ?)}";
Map<String, Object> resultMap = jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(procedureCall);
                callableStatement.setString(1, "param1Data");
                callableStatement.setString(3, "param3Data");
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
                return callableStatement;
            }
        }, paramList);
System.out.println("Return out value:"+resultMap.get("firstName"));
```

**Sample2:-**

```
SimpleJdbcCall caller = new SimpleJdbcCall(unityJdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        caller.withProcedureName("GETLINK")
                .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("p_links",OracleTypes.CURSOR, new LinkTypeMapper()),
                        new SqlParameter("p_link_id", Types.VARCHAR));
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(
                "p_link_id", linkGroupId);
        Map<String,Object>  results = caller.execute(params);
        return new LinkGroup((Collection<Link>) results.get("p_links"),linkGroupId);
```

I googled further and found that have to write rowMapper class and register the INOUT param (considering INOUT as OUT)

Comment: You can register inout parameter by declareParameter( new SqlInOutParameter("inoutparam",OracleTypes.INTEGER));

Comment: That's just one part of it glad if you could share some working code around the same.